# Collection.Contains Big-O

Tags: c#, optimization, collections, big-o

I need to optimize a feature which displays the number of alarms for the system, which gets unbearable slow when it reaches 20 000 alarms. (An alarm consists of an alarm, and a condition, meaning it's actually 40 000 objects). This number is refreshed each 5 second.

Now, never mind that the only thing needed is an integer and that the previous programmer achieved this by:

1. Load every alarm and condition from the database on every call (acknowledged and unacknowledged)
2. Iterate through every alarm to find the unacknowledged alarms (With some custom Linq extension)
3. Send that list of unacknowledged alarms, and the matching list of conditions, to the Silverlight application
4. Compare the list of unacknowledged alarms to the cached list of unacknowledged alarms
5. Repeat 4. for conditions
6. Bind Labels to `Alarms.Count` and `Conditions.Count`

This obviously causes a lot of unneeded overhead, which I'm planning to solve by replacing everything with the SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as UnAckAlarms
FROM Alarms
WHERE AckTime IS NULL
```

But no, what I was wondering was step 4.
There I found this:

```
foreach (var alarm in loadResult.Entities)
{
    if (!ActiveAlarms.Contains(alarm.AlarmId))
    {
        ActiveAlarms.Add(new AlarmInfo
        (...)
```

Alarm is an object, with no hash, as far as I know, and so I wondered.. Is the bigO for Collection`.Contains()` O(n)? And in that case, wouldn't the above code have a O(n^2)? And, if I optimize this code to O(n), or even O(1) by replacing the whole collection, would I get a 0.99% speed increase? (40000/400000^2)
Or should I just replace everything with the SQL statement and rewrite major parts of the application?

edit: So, some results:
Before optimization: 60+ seconds for total get
After removing unnecessary loops and custom adds: 8 seconds. ~7 seconds were loading times from server, so:
After server side optimization: 0.3 seconds.

That's about a 200% speed increase. :)

Comment: Which type of collection are you talking about?

Comment: In this case, ObservableCollection(T), but I believe it inherits most methods from Collection(T).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `ActiveAlarms` is of type `Collection` or `List`, and is not implemented using a Hash, then the `Contains()` is of O(n), and the code above is indeed of O(n^2).

If you could change `ActiveAlarms` to be a hash collection, then the `Contains()` would be of O(1) and the entire code above would become O(n). The question is whether O(1) is actually much faster than O(n), that would depend on how complicated the internal hash function of the hash table would be. But I think we can be certain that it would be faster in most normal cases.

The exact speed increase you would get is unpredictable. Measure and find out, I'd say!

Good luck!

Comment: As these Alarms each has an unique id, I began examining how to use that in a hash function. Turns out it was somewhat lousy implemented already: The add function did a second loop through the Collection, to find the item where AlarmID > item.AlarmID. Ok, so another O(n). And what happened when that condition were fullfilled?  Collection.Insert, which also has O(n). In conclusion, I had not O(n^2) but somewhere between O(n^2) and O(n^4).... Removed all that nonsense, and got my 98% speed increase. (From 30 sec to 0.8 sec). And that's good enough for now. Later I'll implement proper hashing.

Answer (score 1):

I would move this whole thing into sql.  Create a set of triggers that add/subtract from a running total whenever an alarm is added/removed/acknowledged/etc.  The running loop just to count things is not necessary at all

Comment: I did some further measuring, and it turns out step 1, 2 and 3 did not take unreasonable time. But how does triggers to update a field compare to a SQL count() statement?